# Turn management between 2 players

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm new to android and was developing a quiz game. My problem is that when the second player connects to the game, where the first player is already waiting, the second player's game page closes while the first player doesn't. To manage the player's turn, I created a reference to the "turn" node and then on the "setQuiz()" method I used the reference to retrieve the username of the player who has the turn. Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
package com.example.genialone;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.genialone.data.RealtimeDatabase;
import com.example.genialone.model.TurnManager;
import com.example.genialone.model.Utente;
import com.example.genialone.preference.PreferencesManager;
import com.example.genialone.util.RandomCategory;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class GiocoActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Button next;
    private PreferencesManager preferencesManager;

    private TextView opponent;
    private CircleImageView imageOpponent;

    private TextView player;
    private CircleImageView imagePlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    private TextView question;
    private Button option1, option2, option3, option4;
    private String rightAnswer;
    private String player1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gioco);

        player = findViewById(R.id.player);
        imagePlayer = findViewById(R.id.imagePlayer);

        opponent = findViewById(R.id.opponent);
        imageOpponent = findViewById(R.id.imageOpponent);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);

        option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);

        preferencesManager = new PreferencesManager(GiocoActivity.this);
        player1 = preferencesManager.getUsername();

        next = findViewById(R.id.continuaButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // next turn
            }
        });

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GiocoActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("In cerca di un avversario...");
        progressDialog.show();

        startGame();
    }

    public void loadProfilePhoto(String user, CircleImageView imageProfilePhoto) {
        DatabaseReference imageRef = database.getReference("Utenti").child(user);

        imageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("imagineProfilo").getValue(String.class);
                Glide.with(GiocoActivity.this).load(imageUrl)
                        .placeholder(com.firebase.ui.database.R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                        .circleCrop()
                        .error(com.firebase.ui.database.R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                        .into(imageProfilePhoto);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Gestione degli errori
            }
        });
    }

    private void startGame() {
        player.setText(player1);
        loadProfilePhoto(player1, imagePlayer);
        DatabaseReference connectionRef = database.getReference("connections");
        Query availableConnections = connectionRef.orderByChild("player2").equalTo(null);

        availableConnections.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot gameSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String connectionId = gameSnapshot.getKey();
                        connectionRef.child(connectionId).child("player2").setValue(player1);
                        join(connectionId);
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    DatabaseReference newRef = database.getReference("connections").push();
                    String connectionId = newRef.getKey();
                    assignPlayersToGame(connectionId, player1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void join(String connectionId) {
        DatabaseReference connectionRef = database.getReference("connections").child(connectionId);

        connectionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String usernameOpponent = snapshot.child("player1").getValue(String.class);
                showInfoOpponent(usernameOpponent);
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private String playerTurn;
    private String turnKey;

    private void assignPlayersToGame(String connectionId, String username) {
        DatabaseReference connectionRef = database.getReference("connections").child(connectionId);
        DatabaseReference turnRef = database.getReference("turn");
        turnKey = turnRef.push().getKey();

        Map<String, Object> playerData = new HashMap<>();
        playerData.put("player1", username);
        connectionRef.updateChildren(playerData);
        turnRef.updateChildren(playerData);

        connectionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String usernameOpponent = snapshot.child("player2").getValue(String.class);

                if (usernameOpponent != null) {
                    showInfoOpponent(usernameOpponent);
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showInfoOpponent(String username) {
        DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("Utenti");

        usersRef.child(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Utente opponentInfo = snapshot.getValue(Utente.class);
                opponent.setText(opponentInfo.getNomeUtente()); // username
                loadProfilePhoto(opponentInfo.getNomeUtente(), imageOpponent); // image profile
                loadPage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setQuiz(String questionD, ArrayList<String> options, String answer) {
        DatabaseReference turnRef = database.getReference("turn").child(turnKey);

        turnRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                playerTurn = snapshot.child("player1").getValue(String.class);
                if (player1.equals(playerTurn)) {
                    question.setText(questionD);
                    rightAnswer = answer;
                    Button[] buttons = {option1, option2, option3, option4};

                    for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
                        buttons[i].setText(options.get(i));
                    }
                    next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GiocoActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Gestione degli errori
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadPage() {
        DatabaseReference quizRef = database.getReference("Quiz");
        String category = RandomCategory.getCategory();

        quizRef.child(category).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int idQuestion = RandomCategory.getQuestion();
                String quest = snapshot.child("Domande").child(String.valueOf(idQuestion)).getValue(String.class);
                ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot opt : snapshot.child("Opzioni").child(String.valueOf(idQuestion)).getChildren()) {
                    String currentOpt = opt.getValue(String.class);
                    options.add(currentOpt);
                }
                String rightA = snapshot.child("Risposta").child(String.valueOf(idQuestion)).getValue(String.class);
                setQuiz(quest, options, rightA);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).